# Why is a calloc function call messing up this struct value?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, graph, calloc

C beginner. I'm trying to implement a graph, and I have these structs:

```
typedef struct GraphNode{
        void *key;
        void *data;
        void **edges;
} GraphNode;

typedef struct Graph {
        int nodes_count;
        void **nodes_list;
        void **edges_list;
} Graph;
```

The `Graph` struct is basically just holding two arrays with all the nodes and edges added so far. It also has `nodes_count` which I want to increment each time I add a node. I want each `GraphNode` struct to have a `key`, `data`, and an array of all connecting edges.

I have an insert function:

```
int Graph_insert(Graph *map, void *key, void *data)
{       
        GraphNode *node = Graph_node_create(key, data);
        map->nodes_count++;
        
        /** add node to map->nodes_list here **/
}
```

Which uses `Graph_node_create`:

```
GraphNode *Graph_node_create(void *key, void *data)
{
        GraphNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(GraphNode));

        node->key = key;
        node->data = data;
        node->neighbors = calloc(DEFAULT_MAX_NEIGHBOR_COUNT, sizeof(Edge *));

        return node;
}
```

The issue is when I call `Graph_node_create`. It seems to be creating a `GraphNode *node` and returning it, but after doing so `map->nodes_count` is messed up and shows a nonsense value. If I change the functions slightly and pass the `Graph *map` to `Graph_node_create` for the sole purpose of tracking `map->nodes_count`, and then print `map->nodes_count` like so:

```
GraphNode *Graph_node_create(Graph *map, void *key, void *data)
{
        GraphNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(GraphNode));

        printf("map->nodes_count: %d\n", map->nodes_count);
        node->key = key;
        printf("map->nodes_count: %d\n", map->nodes_count);

        ...
}
```

I get the following when running a unit test:

```
RUNNING: ./tests/graph_tests
map->nodes_count: 0
map->nodes_count: 73081008
```

It seems like whatever is happening is happening when first assigning the passed `key` to `node->key`, but I can't figure out why. It seems like some memory is being overwritten or something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(For the sake of completeness here is the `Edge` struct. I don't think its pertinent to the question tho.)

```
typedef struct Edge {
        GraphNode *from;
        GraphNode *to;
        int weight;
} Edge;
```

Comment: Why are you using `void*` as the type of `GraphNode.key` ?

Comment: Run it with AddressSanitizer or Valgrind.

Comment: How do you know how many edges are recorded in the graph?  Surely you need to know that number too?  Similarly in the graph node structure; you need a way to identify how many edges there are.   It's not obvious why you're using `void *` for the edges.  It's more understandable to use `void *` for the key and the value, but using them comes with some complexity in memory management.

Comment: Your code references `node->neighbors` — but your structures have no such member.  The code you are showing isn't the code you are compiling, and we can't reliably debug hypothetical code.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: @wrosen01, Tip: avoid getting the size wrong.  Size to the referenced object, not type.  `node->neighbors = calloc(DEFAULT_MAX_NEIGHBOR_COUNT, sizeof(Edge *));` --> `node->neighbors = calloc(DEFAULT_MAX_NEIGHBOR_COUNT, sizeof node->neighbors[0]);`

Comment: @Dai because I wanted to see if I could make the code work with both char * keys and bstring keys from Better String Library

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks that's very good advice I'll try to adhere to that in future

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*This is mostly tangential to your main problem (but it's too long to fit in a comment).*</sup>

You should revise your code to avoid `void *` or `void **` values, at least for the lists of nodes and edges.  You should also count both the nodes and the edges.  You can forward declare your structure types so that you can use their names accurately:

```
typedef struct GraphNode GraphNode;
typedef struct Graph Graph;
typedef struct Edge Edge;

struct GraphNode
{
    void    *key;
    void    *data;
    size_t   edges_count;
    Edge   **edges;
};

struct Graph
{
    size_t      nodes_count;
    size_t      edges_count;
    GraphNode **nodes_list;
    Edge      **edges_list;
};

struct Edge
{
    GraphNode *from;
    GraphNode *to;
    int weight;
};
```

None of this explains why you're running into problems with `calloc()`.  However, part of the trouble could be tracking the levels of indirection accurately.

For example, you must have allocated the key and the data so that you can store those pointers in the graph — and you must not free those values until you release the graph.  Using the `Edge **edges;` means you will allocate an array of pointers, and then fill those pointers in.  You might need two values for the number of edges in a graph node — one for the number of pointers allocated (sometimes called the capacity) and one for the number of edges stored.  I often use names like `edges_max` and `edges_num` (or `max_edges` and `num_edges`) for the two elements.  Similar comments apply to the lists in the graph structure.  It isn't clear how you're keeping track of all this.